# Problem in executing the batch file in winscp

Tags: windows, batch-file, winscp

I am new to Winscp and I am having a problem in executing a batch file.

The scenario is something like this:

I have a batch file A, two folders (up B and down folders C), some text files in up folder D, a text file E (different from the files in D) and a ppk file F. All these things are in one folder only.

The batch file A is having a script (script is shown below) which contains text. If that text contents are true (means if that text (text contents are related to E i.e. if the text file E is executed) is executed) then only the files in up folder B moves to down folder C.

And the script in batch file A is:

```
C:\somefolder\WinSCP3.exe /console /script=E.txt /log=session.log
if errorlevel 1 goto error
xcopy C:\somefolder\up\*.*  C:\somefolder\down\  /y
del  C:\somefolder\up\*.*   /Q
:error
echo Upload failed, keeping local files
```

And the content in text file E is:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open @test.com 
change remote directory
cd \somedirectory
option transfer binary
put C:\somefolder\up\*.*
close
exit
```

I don't know why the files from up folder is not moving to down folder.

Please let me know where exactly the problem is and how to resolve that problem....

Comment: The batch file seems nothing unusual to me except the opening line: `C:\somefolder=E.txt /log=C:\somefolder\session.log`. Is this something Winscp-specific? Because if it's not, the line seems problematic and most probably mistaken. What should it do? (Or what *does* it do?)

Comment: Thanks for giving me some comment...Actually C:\somefolder=E.txt means the process will go to that file and try to execute that text file E. And /log=C:\somefolder\session.log this thing will create a session log.

Comment: I got some improvement...But still its not copying the text files D from up folder to down folder. I am gonna edit the question to improved level...

Comment: Hi All, I updated some of the codes like the  C:\somefolder\WinSCP3.exe /console /script=E.txt /log=session.log
and open @test.com. Now this overall process is creating a session and copying the file in \somedirectory. But still its not copying the data in down folder and and deleting the up folder data...

Comment: How do you know it is not copying and not deleting? Seems like your script would print the error message even if it did all the job, because you don't have a `goto` after the `del` line which should jump over the error message. That is, if you are judging by the error message, then it can be misleading for the reasons I've just mentioned.

Comment: Yes that's true....I just tried the goto syntax after the del line...its working now...cool thanks a lot....

Comment: Good job! You can post that as an answer to your own question and accept it, for people to see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andriy M. His comments cleared my confusion and gave the right answer.

Here are the right syntax.

```
C:\somefolder\WinSCP3.exe /console /script=E.txt /log=session.log

xcopy C:\somefolder\up\*.*  C:\somefolder\down\  /y
del  C:\somefolder\up\*.*   /Q

if errorlevel 1 goto error

:error
echo Upload failed, keeping local files
```

The content in text file E.txt is:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open @test.com 
change remote directory
cd \somedirectory
option transfer binary
put C:\somefolder\up\*.*
close
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if anyone still read this thread or not..
But what I know is "put" command upload the files from Local Directory to Remote Directory.
TS wanted to "download the files from Remote Directory to Local Directory" so I think the right command is "get".

Cheers,
Shen