# Backup and upload to FTP server

Tags: batch-file, upload, ftp, open-source, backup

Can anyone direct me to a script solution that makes a backup of a directory and uploads it to an ftp server?

I was searching for a batch script initially but any solution would do, as long as it is open source.

Thanks in advance,
Jean

Comment: Are you able to use 7-zip to create a zip file and upload that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be working on one soon, but WinSCP has a CLI that you can use to accomplish this:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

There are plenty examples using WinSCP on stackoverflow and on other sites, like:
[Batch file when using WinSCP and command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692691/batch-file-when-using-winscp-and-command-prompt)
[Problem in executing the batch file in winscp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382964/problem-in-executing-the-batch-file-in-winscp)

You can use this url get more examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file+winscp

Please keep in mind WinSCP isn't the only solution for this, it's the one that I use at work :).

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'll keep everyone updated on how it goes.

Comment: You're welcome, keep us posted if you can